# react.js - how to change icon to image

Tags: reactjs

{label: 'Cooling Chamber', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-id-card', routerLink: ['/uikit/floatlabel'] }

how to insert image into the above code instead of icon ? replacing icon to image: {"assets/layout/images/motor.jpeg"} doesn't worked

replacing icon to image: {"assets/layout/images/motor.jpeg"} doesn't worked

Comment: { label: <><img src="assets/layout/images/motor.jpeg" alt="Motor" /> Cooling Chamber</>, routerLink: ['/uikit/floatlabel'] }
try this

Comment: please provide more info